# Multiple GPUs machine with more than one PSU

Tags: graphics-cards, power-supply, power

Does anyone have experience with using a machine for training Deep Learning models (R-CNNs for semantic segmentation), using multiple GPUs and powering it with more that one PSU? E.g. one PSU for motherboard and one GPU only, and another PSU for a second (and more?) GPU connected to the same motherboard.

Comment: This is certainly possible. Are you looking for something professional like what you'd find in a rendering server, or something "hacky" that could be done with normal desktop PSUs?

Comment: I will definitely start with something hacky!
I may even go for an "open box", just a frame without enclosing walls.

Answer (score 0):

for consumer home pc style ATX power supplies, you would not use more than one to a motherboard.  They have the 24-pin ATX motherboard connector, for connecting to only one motherboard.  If this is the kind of rig you are looking to do multiple gpu's you simply buy a 1000w or 1200w psu that supplies 4 pcie 6 or 8 pin power connectors for gpu's.

There is the *enterprise* route that uses rack mount type chassis and rack mount power supplies.  For example a Dell R940xa, 4U in height, has 4 x 1600w power supplies; it runs on 208/240v power.  They along with Supermicro you can peruse their websites to look at their offerings to get an idea of how it's done, where they can support I think up to 10  nvidia-V100 type gpgpu's (double width, like a consumer grade RTX3090, having 1x or 2x 6 or 8 pin power connectors per card)

a home built pc, using a full size tower with an ATX or extended ATX size motherboard, will accomodate 2 typical RTX-3090 cards, you just need a common ATX power supply in the 800w plus range that will provide the necessary pcie power cables to the graphics card(s).  you would never use 2 psu's on one motherboard for a home pc type rig, you would get one PSU providing enough power for the hardware to be used.